# Calculate distance traveled with opposite force being applied to item travelling

Tags: classical-mechanics

An item moves for $20$ seconds on a straight path with a beginning velocity of $20m/s$. For this entire duration, a force $(X)$ is added to the item which results in this item decelerating at $6m/s^2$. What is the items’ distance from its initial point after the entire 20 seconds have passed?

I think, distance = (speed)(time) = (20)(20) = 400m.

And also, distance = (speed)(time) = (6)(20) = 120m.

Therefore, distance traveled over 20 seconds is 400m – 120m = 280m.

Is this correct? I am worried that I might be oversimplifying this.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen the formula $$s=ut + \dfrac{1}{2}at^2$$

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let apply

$$s=v_ot+\frac12at^2$$

with

- $v_0=20 m/s$
- $a=-6 m/s^2$
- $t=20 s$

$$\implies s=v_ot+\frac12at^2=400-\frac126\cdot400=-800 \,m$$

Answer (score 0):

You have a particle moving with constant acceleration so you need to use suvat equations

In this case you have $a=-6,u=20,t=20$ and you can use the equation $s=ut+\frac 12at^2$ to get $s=-800$ so the distance from the initial point is $800$

Answer (score 0):

With physicist notations:
$$F=m\ddot{r}$$
$$\frac{F}{m}=\ddot{r}$$
$$a=\ddot{r}$$
$$-6=\ddot{r}$$
$$-6=\dot{v}$$
Integrating both sides with respect to $t$:
$$\int\limits_{t=0}^{t}-6\mathrm{d}t=\int\limits_{v=20}^{v}\mathrm{d}v$$
$$-6t=v-20$$
$$v(t)=20-6t$$
$$\dot{r}=v$$
$$r(t)=\int\limits_{t=0}^{t}20-6t\mathrm{d}t$$
$$r(t)=20t-3t^2$$
You are looking for $r(20)$:
$$r(20)=20*20-3*20^2=-800\text{m}$$
So it will be $800$m away from the initial position.